# Python regex to match quoted string with escaped single quotes

Tags: python, regex, single-quotes

I was using this pattern to match single quoted strings in parser:

```
"'.+?'"
```

But I need regex that can find single quoted string with postgres like escape of single qoutes (doubling single qoutes). Need to match something like this:

```
"'first', 'sec''ond', 't''hi''rd'"
```

I want to find shortest matches for strings that start and end with single single quotes, so the string above would mean 3 substrings:

```
'first'
'sec''ond'
't''hi''rd'
```

Comment: Nested structures **shouldn't** be handled with regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly, [`'(?:[^']|'')*'`](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2wH2/1) is the working regex for this: it matches a `'` followed with zero or more characters other than `'` or double `'`s followed with a trailing `'`.

However, to make it more efficient, you can *unroll* it using the [**unroll-the-loop technique**](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop).

```
'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2wH2/2) and pay attention how many steps it takes for the regexps to find all matches.

The regex can be read as

- `'` - match a `'`
- `[^']*` - then zero or more characters other than `'`
- `(?:''[^']*)*` - then zero or more sequences of `''` followed with zero or more characters other than `'`
- `'` - and then match the trailing `'`.

This regex has a linear pattern involving as little backtracking as possible.

Just a note: you can still make *your* regex work for the current scenario if you add a lookahead checking if there is a `,` or the end of string after the trailing `'`:

```
'.+?'(?=,|$)
     ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2wH2/3). However, it is context dependent and less efficient than the unrolled regex.

Answer (score 2):

`'(?:[^']|'{2})+'`

a single quote, followed by greedy occurrences of:

- either a character that is not a single quote
- or two single quotes together

followed by a single quote.

demo: https://regex101.com/r/zP2eK6/1

Answer (score 1):

For the pattern you supplied this should work:

`'[\w']+'`

That is match a single quote followed by one or more non-whitespace or single quote followed by a final single quote.